# How to just show subtotals for each column in a report?

Tags: reporting, count

I'm having trouble doing something supposedly very simple, can anyone tell me how I can display the record count for each column in a report?

Knowing that each column is a picklist field that can have the values "Yes", "No", or blank, I'd want to show at the bottom of the column the number "5" if 5 records had a "Yes".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question you want to group your fields based on picklist values.
In that case you need to

1. Go to the report
2. Add Group rows and choose an option how you want to group your records (in your case it will be a picklist)
3. The result
   [image]

If it is not what you want, please, update description with example report/fields